# Effectively Decreasing Website Load Time [SEO Perspective]

Tags: seo

As we know that website load time is now an important factor in Search Engine ranking and Google, especially, is taking this into account. Now I've study all those techniques like minimize http requests, compress css, javascript at footer, compressed images and so on. But sadly they are not putting a great impact on the load time on my blog.

Google webmaster tools says that my average blog-page loads time is 11.8 sec which is slower than 98% of the sites. This is really making me worried as I receive handsome traffic from Google and I don't want to lose that.

Can anybody suggest a technique that can reduce the time massively, to 2-3 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, 
11.8 sec is pretty slow (so slow i would call site seriously broken)

its so slow i would investigate if your blog has technical problems. use a tool like pingdom http://tools.pingdom.com/ and loads.in (click on Waterfall chart after the first test) to find out what is slow. if it's the first part (HTML delivery) then you must investigate what is the slow part (the server, the database, ...) for this look at you internal logfiles and run some DB test scripts (google it).

lets say that from a technical point everything is ok (which i seriously doubt) - or - you dont have the knowledge or tools to find the issue....... then change your webhosting provider. find out (via google analytics) where the majority from your users come from and then choose a - good (so not the cheapest) - in the same country / region.

what i outlined above was the right way to do it, now some quick tips: 
if you are on a cheap webhost, try disabling gzip (which is default enabled via a lot of caching plugins) gzip kills a lot of cheap webhosts (i"m looking at you one.com). 
change your template to a default template, a lot of customized templates are created by web design students on LSD - and are just overkill.

note: 11.8 sec also means that about 20% to 40% of your visitors don't wait for the first pageload. so if you fix it you will see an immediate traffic growth (and more average page views, too).

Comment: The hosting servers are 'wiredtree' located in UK. These tools are showing 5-7 seconds for most pages, which looks fine but google webmaster shows 11s and I myself experience slow loads (here in pakistan). Here's one of the heavy post: (maybe you can figure out any problem or give some suggestions, thanks) http://www.hardwareinsight.com/top-10-expected-pc-games-of-2011/

Comment: I just realized that load.in takes 20s to load this page first time (which most users are) but takes only 6s second time (probably cached): http://www.hardwareinsight.com/top-10-expected-pc-games-of-2010/ (this link is different from the previous)

Comment: where do most of your users come from (Google analytics -> map overview)

Comment: ok, quite simple: you have 141 HTTP Requests on a first load, that is quite simple: too much, try to reduce it to ... 10-20. the 141 requests add up to that long loadtime. (how: combine all css to one css, combine all js to one js, combine all small images to sprites (and make the big images smaller with optPNG) ... get rid of any plugin (technorati) and widget that you do not absolutely need, overwork your tracking strategy, get rid of all of it) and get also take another good look into how you load your ads.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to implement all of these.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple css, this way can make decrease your site loading.

here this example:

```
#header{width:950px;height:80px;margin-top:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:0px;}
```